# Simple slopes test for merMod object with R package interactions (jtools)

Tags: r, mixed-models, interaction

I'm trying to conduct a simple slopes analysis for a mixed effects model obtained with `lmer`.

The model is similar to the following:

```
data(Orthodont,package="nlme")
mod <- lme4::lmer(distance ~ age*Sex + (1|Subject), data=Orthodont)
```

When trying to conduct a simple slopes analysis with the function `sim_slopes` in the package `interactions`, I obtain the following error message.

```
interactions::sim_slopes(model=mod, pred=age, modx=Sex)
```

> Error: One of the requested columns does not exist.
>   Backtrace:
>   1. interactions::sim_slopes(model = mod, pred = age, modx = Sex)
>   5. jtools:::summ.merMod(...)
>   6. jtools:::create_table(...)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   Johnson-Neyman intervals are not available for factor moderators.

**Would any one have any thoughts on what the problem might be?**

Note that it works well with the package `reghelper`, but I need p values for these tests, which `reghelper` does not provide.

```
reghelper::simple_slopes(mod)
```

The output of `sessionInfo()` is:

> R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
>   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2
>   LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1 LAPACK:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8         [4] LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8
>   LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8     [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
>   [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        magrittr_1.5       splines_3.6.0      MASS_7.3-51.1
>   [5] munsell_0.5.0      colorspace_1.4-1   lattice_0.20-38    rlang_0.3.4
>   [9] minqa_1.2.4        plyr_1.8.4         tools_3.6.0       grid_3.6.0
>   [13] gtable_0.3.0       nlme_3.1-140       cli_1.1.0          assertthat_0.2.1
>   [17] digest_0.6.19      lme4_1.1-21        lazyeval_0.2.2     tibble_2.1.2
>   [21] crayon_1.3.4       Matrix_1.2-17      reghelper_0.3.4    nloptr_1.2.1
>
> [25] ggplot2_3.1.1      interactions_1.1.0 jtools_2.0.1       pander_0.6.3
>   [29] compiler_3.6.0     pillar_1.4.1       scales_1.0.0       boot_1.3-20
>   [33] pkgconfig_2.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by detaching lmerTest.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer but way too long for a comment.  Will delete later if appropriate.)

In a clean R session, this works for me:

```
data(Orthodont,package="nlme")
mod <- lme4::lmer(distance ~ age*Sex + (1|Subject), data=Orthodont)
interactions::sim_slopes(model=mod, pred=age, modx=Sex)
sessionInfo()
```

> SIMPLE SLOPES ANALYSIS 
>   Slope of age when Sex = Female:
>    Est.   S.E.    t val.      p
>   ------ ------ -------- ------
>    0.48   0.09     5.13   0.00
>   Slope of age when Sex = Male: 
>    Est.   S.E.   t val.      p 
>   ------ ------ -------- ------
>     0.78   0.08    10.12   0.00
>   Warning message:
>   Johnson-Neyman intervals are not available for factor moderators.

Here is my `sessionInfo()`: the important stuff looks the same as yours (`lme4` 1.1-21, `interactions` 1.1.0, `jtools` 2.0.1), but it's certainly not identical ... ??

```
R Under development (unstable) (2019-05-21 r76566)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

[matrix product and locale info deleted]   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1         magrittr_1.5       splines_3.7.0      MASS_7.3-51.4     
 [5] tidyselect_0.2.5   munsell_0.5.0      colorspace_1.4-1   lattice_0.20-38   
 [9] R6_2.4.0           rlang_0.3.4        minqa_1.2.4        plyr_1.8.4        
[13] dplyr_0.8.1        tools_3.7.0        grid_3.7.0         gtable_0.3.0      
[17] nlme_3.1-140       cli_1.1.0          digest_0.6.19      assertthat_0.2.1  
[21] lme4_1.1-21        lazyeval_0.2.2     tibble_2.1.2       numDeriv_2016.8-1 
[25] crayon_1.3.4       Matrix_1.2-17      purrr_0.3.2        nloptr_1.2.1      
[29] ggplot2_3.1.1      jtools_2.0.1       interactions_1.1.0 glue_1.3.1        
[33] pander_0.6.3       compiler_3.7.0     pillar_1.4.1       scales_1.0.0      
[37] lmerTest_3.1-0     boot_1.3-22        pkgconfig_2.0.2
```