# Probing two-way interaction in R using lme4 - grand-mean centred

Tags: r, lme4, interaction, multi-level

I am trying to probe a two-way interaction in R using lme4. I have found a solution for the package lavaan (https://rdrr.io/cran/semTools/man/probe2WayMC.html) but I need to do it in lme4. My predictors are grand-mean centred.

Could anybody help me out please? My model looks like this:

```
h5_c_t <- lmer(PSS_mean ~ WLoad_mean_gmc * PCT_mean_gmc + sex_m + Age_gmc + startup_m + (1 | teamcode), data = dat)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Sarah

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the term "probe." I found an explanation here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304435162_Testing_and_probing_interactions_in_hierarchical_linear_growth_models

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, sorry. Because it is multilevel and grand-mean centred the interaction effect has to be tested again to check whether it is "true". You can read about it here: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.3102/10769986031004437?casa_token=XuwD1u003_sAAAAA:Tb4r7hZIvtYDDcIwGLHMxVs08FpQvP8dvvWXt2JcSlrelopkxA2SGYUNgZWlY6ethQeT2lrSnEfR9w

Comment: The only problem I have is that I do not know how to do it with lme4 in R...

Comment: I wonder if this is a helpful lead: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56401996/8400969

Comment: Or this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reghelper/versions/0.3.4